# UITableView reloadData

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have one `UITableView`.

```
UITabelView *tabelView;
[tabelView reloadData];
```

but this `reloadData` function is not calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or `numberOfRowsInSection`. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You need to provide more information. How are you creating the UITableView? In code or with a XIB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
[self.tabelView reloadData];
```